# Check if the equality holds

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem. For orthogonal $8\times 8$ matrix $M$ ($M\cdot M^{T} = 1$) check if the following equality holds

$$
U = M^{T} \cdot \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1_{3\times 3} & 0\\
                                          0 & 0_{5\times 5}
                       \end{array}\right) \cdot M
$$
where $U$ can be any of these

$$U \in \{ \text{diag}(1,0,\ldots,0), \text{diag}(0,1,0,\ldots,0), \ldots, \text{diag}(0,\ldots,0,1)\}.$$
This is not a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The trace of your possible $U$s is $1$, the trace of the matrix from above is $3$. Changing the basis of a matrix doesn't change the trace.

Comment: Perfect answer :)